# Using Principal Directions and Curvatures to Find Point On Surface

Tags: geometry, surfaces, curvature, curves

Given the principal directions (max and min), principal curvatures, and normal of a surface at point n, how would you go about looking for a point on the surface at a given vector distance from n?

I'm trying to create a Solidworks Addin to map a spline to a surface and have limited mathematical knowledge (up to diff eq).

Comment: You only have information about the surface in the neighborhood of a $n$, so you can't be sure how the surface behaves at any finite distance away from $n$. You can assume that the surface is smooth with constant principal curvatures (so that $n$ is at the apex of a perfect ellipsoid), then the locus of points a given distance from $n$ is a sphere and you can intersect the sphere with the ellipsoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you mean by "vector distance", but I'll take a shot, anyway.

Suppose you have a point $P$ on a surface $S$, and you want to find another point $Q$ on $S$ whose distance from $P$ is equal to some given number $d$.

The solution depends on how you choose to measure distance.

If your distance measure is the length of the chord $PQ$, then it's fairly easy. You construct a sphere of radius $d$ with center at $P$, and intersect it with $S$. Any point $Q$ on the intersection curve has the desired property.

If you want to measure distance along planar section curves, that's also fairly easy. Take a plane through $P$ that contains the surface normal vector at $P$. Intersect this plane with the surface $S$. Then find a point $Q$ on this intersection curve at a distance $d$ from $P$. Most CAD systems have a function to find a point at a given distance along a curve from some other one.

Even without the "point-at-distance-along-a-curve" function, there's a way to construct a reasonable approximation. Suppose your principal curvatures are $k_1$ and $k_2$, and your tangent direction $T$ makes an angle $\theta$ with the direction of $k_1$. Then a [theorem of Euler](http://web.mit.edu/hyperbook/Patrikalakis-Maekawa-Cho/node34.html) tells us that the normal curvature $k_n$ in the plane containing $T$ is given by
$$
k_n = k_1 \cos^2 \theta + k_2 \sin^2 \theta
$$
This is the curvature of the planar section containing $T$ and the surface normal, so you can use it to construct a circular arc that approximates the planar section. Then measure distance along this circular arc, which is easy.

Another way to measure distance is along curves called geodesics. If your math knowledge is limited, you probably want to stay away from these.

My answers assume (mostly) that you have the surface $S$. If you don't have it, you can use the curvature information at $P$ to build a second-order approximation of $S$ (like an ellipsoid), as the comment above suggests, or you can approximate planar sections by arcs, using Euler's theorem, as above.

Many CAD systems have this sort of functionality built in.

Comment: Thank you, @bubba. I should have specified, but meant the actual surface distance and not the chord. How would you use the second-order approximation of the curvatures to calculate an approximate distance over the surface? Pretty certain this is the direction I'd like to go with.

Comment: Distance along some planar section, or distance along a geodesic?

Comment: Given a starting point, a direction and distance to move, and a surface, I need to find the coinciding point on the surface. I believe this would be the geodesic distance. @bubba

Comment: It's your choice. There is a geodesic curve with the given start tangent, and there is a planar cross-section curve. Unless you have some very strong reason to believe that the geodesic is the "correct" answer, I would avoid it, because computing it is pretty difficult. Planar section lengths are much easier. In most cases,  for smallish offsets, the results will be the same to within engineering/manufacturing tolerances

Comment: Or, even easier, measure distance along circular arcs that approximate planar sections. See additions to my answer for info about how to do this.

Comment: The Euler theorem seems to be exactly what I need. Saw it before, but now it makes sense. Thanks so much, @bubba! :))